# WebSphere 8.5 integration with spring-web 3.2.17

Tags: web-services, websphere

**The context:**

I am involved with porting an application from running on WebSphere 7.0 to WebSphere 8.5.5.10. The application is calling web services.

**The pattern:**

When the web service endpoint is called first time it works just fine. 
But on the subsequent calls it fails receiving the same SOAP request.

**The error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value for the "java.lang.Object" parameter cannot be null.
org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsSoapFaultException: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value for the "java.lang.Object" parameter cannot be null.; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value for the "java.lang.Object" parameter cannot be null.
at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.doInvoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:503)
at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.invoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:487)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
```

The error is inside the spring-web-3.2.17.RELEASE.jar.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: You're probably going to need to show some source code. Maybe both the calling (Java) code and any relevant Spring bean configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting via IHS? Maybe you have a cluster and first request is served by other WAS instance.

You might also check JDK version between WAS 7.0 and 8.5.5.10 - if both are the same like java6.

(By the way, instal Fixpack to latest 8.5.5.11)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. To answer your questions:
1) IHS is used but there is no cluster present.
2) JDK 6 is used on both servers (7 and 8.5.5.10).

Not sure if pack 11 will fix the issue but I am inclined to give it a try.

More facts gathered:
In the code excerpt below the Object accessor is NULL, when an inbound message is being sent

// WebSphere specific and only available after 7.0.0.15, for details see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM21151
Object accessor = smc.get("jaxws.message.accessor");

Comment: What I have understand from the PMR you pointed is that soap body is null,so it probably was not received properly. Maybe you need to enable more trace: like https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_tracewbscomp.html by tracing **com.ibm.ws.webservices.trace.MessageTrace=finest:com.ibm.ws.webservices.
engine.Message=finest** and maybe even **org.springframework.remoting.jaxws**